# function inside click() get executed after setting the element's click method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function show1(){
            $("#btn").click(show2());
            window.alert("1st show");
        }

    function show2(){
        $("#btn").click(show3());
        window.alert("2nd show");
    }

        function show3(){
            window.alert("3rd show");
        }


    </script>
    <button id="btn" onclick="show1()">Show</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont understand the behavior of the code above. After setting the `$("#btn").click(show2());`, the function is executed even though I din't clicked the button. **Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are callbacks, you need to follow this

`$("#btn").click(show2);`

or this

`$("#btn").click(function(){ show2(); });`

Otherwise, if you use `show2()`, you will invoke the function because it will not be a reference to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function reference as the event handler, in your case you are invoking the handle function and is passing the value returned by it as the handler

```
$("#btn").click(show2);//no () at the end
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gj5Lu4r4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function show1(){
            $("#btn").click(show2);
            window.alert("1st show");
}
 function show2(){
        window.alert("2nd show");
}
```

Try to catch event by using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
function show1(){
                $("#btn").on("click",show2);
                window.alert("1st show");
    }
     function show2(){
            window.alert("2nd show");
    }
```